# Can a Jmeter Java Request can have Summary Report?

Tags: java, jmeter

Is it possible for a [Java request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Java_Request) to have a [summary report](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) to it. I tried attaching
TPS listener, results tree, results table but could not see the report populated after running in jmeter.
It is not explicitly mentioned jmeter docs, but i assume, It should be supported.But i am not able to see it even after successful run of the test as seen from logs (runTest() method gets called successfully)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is

[image]

The `runTest()` function is supposed to return a [SampleResult](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html) and it's **your job** to call the necessary functions like:

- create a new instance
- call [sampleStart()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#sampleStart--) function when you want to start the measurement
- call [sampleEnd()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#sampleEnd--) function when you want to stop the measurement
- call [setSuccessful()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setSuccessful-boolean-) function to mark the sampler as passed or failed
- call [setResponsecode()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setResponseCode-java.lang.String-) and [setResponseData()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#setResponseData-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) functions to set response code/response body if needed

See [JavaTest](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/protocol/java/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test/JavaTest.java) and [SleepTest](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4.1/src/protocol/java/src/main/java/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/java/test/SleepTest.java) example implementations for reference.

You may also find [JSR223 Sampler with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) easier to use (Java syntax should work in the majority of cases)